# Is it possible to check or clear session variables from an HTML page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, web-applications

I have a web application that uses Visual Basic 2008, C#, and the ASP.NET 3.5 Framework. It consists of five pages:

1. Index (Index.html)
2. About us (AboutUs.html)
3. Contact us (ContactUs.html)
4. User login (Login.aspx)
5. User home (UserHome.aspx)

All pages contain a menu to navigate to all other pages.

Is it possible to clear a session from an HTML page? If a user logs in, navigates to the Contact Us page, then logs out from that page, how can I clear session variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Sessions are server-side variables and can not be changed in the client-side.

Here are some tips:

1. Use masterpages
2. You can use HttpXmlRequest to clear the session
3. Redirect user to page (for example logout.aspx) and in its code
   behind, in `onLoad` Method put this code:

`Session["UserId"] = null; Response.Redirect("Index.html",true);`

Answer (score 0):

you may try to add code like

```
<% Session.Abandon() %>
```

in your HTML page.

This style called inline ASP .net Code.

Note that, inline code still works in all .Net version event in the classic one.